# Bundle Adjustment for Multi-Camera (more than 2) Setup

Tags: opencv, optimization, camera, triangulation, calibration

I am wondering if anyone could help me understand how to use OpenCV's bundle adjustment functions. My project involves 4 to 8 cameras surrounding a capture area where a person will be walking. The goal is to obtain accurate 3D reconstruction of the persons joint centers.

So far I have calibrated camera intrinsic parameters using OpenCV's ChArUco board method, and I have also calibrated stereo pairs (extrinsic parameters) of my cameras [camera 1, camera 2], [camera 2, camera 3], [camera 3, camera 4], etc.
My understanding is that using bundle adjustment should help me to optimise the parameters so that I can get more accurate values when triangulating the joint keypoints.

Could anyone give me some guidance/explanation on what I should be doing?